# Showing that a knowledge base leads to empty clause

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic

Using the resolution method, I want show that the following knowledge leads to the empty clause.

1. $∃x (q(f(x))∧s(f(x),A))$
2. $∀x∀y¬∃z (p(x, y)∧s(x,z))$
3. $∀x (q(x)∧ ∃y s(x, y)) ⇒ (∃z (r(z)∧ p(x,z)))$

What I did so far :

4. $¬(q(x)∧ ∃y s(x, y)) ∨ (∃z (r(z)∧ p(x,z)))$ from 3 as $∀x, A⇒B = ¬A ∨ B$

Then I'm stuck ...

Comment: You posted the [exact same qustion](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/64246/looking-to-prove-that-my-knowledge-bases-leads-to-empty-clause) on Philosophy SE. Please don't post the same question across multiple sites in the network.

Comment: As per comment to the same post in PhilSE, 4. is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

See [Resolution method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resolution_(logic)#Resolution_in_first_order_logic) :

1) produce [clauses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clause_(logic)), using [Skolemization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skolem_normal_form#Examples) if needed.

E.g. $q(f(B))$ and $s(f(B),A))$ from 1. and $¬p(x, y) \lor ¬s(x,z)$ from 2.

*Note* : from 3. (presumably : it depends on the scope of the leading quantifier) we get : $∀x[¬(q(x)∧∃ys(x,y)) \lor ∃z(r(z)∧p(x,z))]$.

Thus, using the rules for [Prnex Normal Form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prenex_normal_form#Conjunction_and_disjunction) we have :

> $∀x∃z∀y[¬q(x) \lor ¬s(x,y) \lor (r(z)∧p(x,z))]$

that means : $¬q(x) \lor ¬s(x,y) \lor (r(g(x))∧p(x,g(x)))$, i.e. two new clauses.

2) Find two clauses containing the same predicate, where it is negated in one clause but not in the other and perform [unification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unification_(computer_science)) on the two predicates.

E.g. use the subst $\{ x \leftarrow f(B), z \leftarrow A \}$ to unify $s(f(B),A))$ with $¬p(x, y) \lor ¬s(x,z)$.

3) apply the [Resolution rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resolution_(logic)#Resolution_rule), discarding the unified predicates, and combine the remaining ones from the two clauses into a new clause.

Applying resolution to the two clauses above (after unification) we get the new caluse : $\lnot p(f(B),y)$.